# Can any user account in Linux invoke command chmod?

Tags: permissions, security

Since permissions are sensitive, is it vital to be clear whether a specific user is or not allowed to run command `chmod`?

Answer (score 5):

No, any user can run this command and should be able to do so. This command is how users can manipulate the permissions bits on a directory or file which is vital for making shell scripts executable or making a directory accessible to groups that the user might be a part of.

#### Examples

1. An executable script

   ```
   $ ls -l reset*
   -rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml   378 Sep  2 02:46 reset_raw_sorted.bash
   ```
2. Accessing a directory

   ```
   $ ls -ld adir
   drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Oct 19 21:28 adir
   ```

   Now disable this directory's execute bits

   ```
   $ chmod -x adir
   $ ls -ld adir
   drw-rw-r-- 2 saml saml 4096 Oct 19 21:28 adir
   ```

   Now I can't `cd` to this directory

   ```
   $ cd adir/
   bash: cd: adir/: Permission denied
   ```
3. Controlling group access to files and directories

   Say I have a user in these groups

   ```
   $ groups
   saml vboxusers jupiter newgrp blah
   ```

   I want to give other users that are in group blah access to `adir`

   ```
   $ ls -ld adir
   drwx---r-x 2 saml blah 4096 Oct 19 21:28 adir
   ```

   I can use `chmod` to remove other user permissions and limit access to user `saml` and group `blah` like so

   ```
   $ chmod o-rwx,g+rwx adir
   $ ls -ld adir
   drwxrwx--- 2 saml blah 4096 Oct 19 21:28 adir
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Any user may call `chmod` and change the permissions of any file that they own (as usual root can of course change any file's permission). Users may not change the permissions of files that they don't own — that would completely destroy file security! The write permission on a file only applies to the file's content, not to its metadata such as permissions.

Unix implements [discretionary access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretionary_Access_Control): the owner of a file is free to allow other users to access that file.

There are forms of mandatory access control, such as Linux's security frameworks (SELinux, AppArmor, etc.) which allows root to restrict access to certain resources in a way that non-root users cannot override. However these are geared towards isolating applications that are running as a dedicated user and limiting the damage that they can do if compromised. They aren't good for implementing mandatory access control among users of the system. If you need MAC, a Unix system with multiple users isn't the right environment, you need a closed system with no network or a very tightly controlled network, no removable drives, etc., and where every user has their own machine.